# How do I search for a text in a string and grab everything after the search text until it reaches a character?

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I am searching a huge html document on the web that will have multiple instances of names. Each section throughout the page source will contain something like this

{"keyword_text":"kathy smith","item_logging_id":"2021-05-16:yakMrD","item_logging_info":"{"source":"entity_bootstrap_connected_user_suggestion",{"keyword_text":"courtney lee","item_logging_id":"2021-05-16:lX1LC2","item_logging_info":"{"source":"entity_bootstrap_connected_user_suggestion",

I want to grab all the names in the source and put them into a text box.

Search the string for "keyword_text":" then grab all text after until it reaches " excluding the "

I want the end result to be

`kathy smith`

`courtney lee`

Comment: Using a regex should solve your problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions

Comment: regex is so confusing to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the "until it reaches the character" you can use the regex `([^\"]*)`

`^` means NOT and `*` means multiple times. So it reads everything until the first appearance of `"`. The `\` is to escape the quotes.

So in your case this is the regex:
`\"keyword_text\":\"([^\"]*)` to get the name-part without quotes.

And in c# context:

```
var matches= new Regex("\"keyword_text\":\"([^\"]*)").Matches(yourInputText);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: This works great for removing only the " around the entire string but what I am trying to do is search for keyword_text":" once it's found grab all text after it until reaching " so that the end results is kathy smith

Comment: That's the case with this regex `\"keyword_text\":\"([^\"]*)`. This part `\"keyword_text\":\"` finds the keyword_text":" and this `([^\"]*)` reads kathy smith until the ".

Comment: When I used this code the result was keyword_text":"kathy staggs

Comment: string name = new Regex("keyword_text\":\"([^\"]*)").Match(strName).Value; When I use this I get a result of keyword_text":"kathy smith when I do txtMain.Text = name that's what I get. I don't get just kathy smith

Comment: Because the result is in the second group. Try `string name = new Regex("\"keyword_text\":\"([^\"]*)").Match(strName).Groups[1].Value;`

Comment: I have another quick question about the same project. Once I find this info the keyword_text and the name how do I remove the results from the var I created to store all this info? I'm pulling all the data from a file putting it into a var and then searching the var for what I need but I need to delete the keyword_text":"kathy smith out of the var after I find it and put it into the textbox so it won't try to enter it into the textbox again after it reaches the end of the search.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Is it about what to do after the regex-parsing? Then I'll need more context.

Comment: This code works great for getting the names so now I want to get their website links which is setup in the same type of structure. I'm trying to use a nested foreach one inside the other to grab the name first then grab the link but for some reason, it's going into an endless loop it won't work. I'm terrible at figuring out how to do loops. I want to grab both of those and then add some HTML code before and after to make it so that I can click their name and it opens their website address. so I need to grab name add code, grab link add code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "Would \"you\" like to have responses to your \"questions\" sent to you via email?";
var reg = new Regex("\".*?\"");
var matches = reg.Matches(str);
foreach (var item in matches)
{
   MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: so to my understanding the way this works is... It searched for the first \ and then searches again till it finds the next \ which would be my " the issue is when it finds the " on my string I need it to leave that " out. I want only the name displayed so the character it stops out needs to be excluded.

Comment: what I am looking for using your example is the result to return the word you without any " on it

Comment: Do you write a real sentence please to compile

Comment: "keyword_text":"kathy smith" grab the name in this example. I want the result kathy smith. The name will be any length but it will always have " at the end.

Comment: "keyword_text":"kathy smith" not a true string for parse.

Comment: string str = @"""How to add doublequotes"""; or string str = "\"How to add doublequotes\"";

Comment: Need JSON parse

Comment: can you explain what the regex is doing each part of it so I can figure out what it's searching for so that I can try and add my code in there. I know I need to escape the " characters in order for it to work but I am not sure where to do it.

Comment: yes exactly I've already escaped the " in my string such as this string strName = "keyword_text\":\"kathy smith\""; but I need the regex to grab only kathy smith. I just don't know how to escape the " in regex since regex is confusing to me

Comment: Can you use "commas" instead of : ?

Comment: "keyword_text", "kathy smith", "Third"

Comment: Remove double qoutes MessageBox.Show(item.ToString().Replace("\"", ""));

Comment: I'm pulling the data from an html document from the web. They always come with the : in them so I'm trying to figure out how to grab only the names with the current code I provided this is how it always shows. It will be data like this that I'm grabbing and I need to pull only the name {"keyword_text":"kathy smith","item_logging_id":"2021-05-16:yakMrD","item_logging_info":"{\"source\": The webpage will have 100s of these names I need to compile.

Comment: I could grab the data put it into a string then replace all : with a , if that would help the regex do a better job or actually work. That's an option the string can be manipulated anyway after it's made.

Comment: I rewrote the entire question to maybe clear things up

Comment: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu Please send an error-free json data using this site and we'll solve the problem.

Comment: {
  "main": {
    "username": "User name",
    "password": "Enter password",
    "app": "Lokalise"
  }
}